# bash script calling itself in while loop - why?

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, solaris

I am trying to understand why this script is calling itself when running.
the script itself works but I cannot figure out the execution of the script after the for loop completes.
it is GNU bash, version 4.4.11(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.11).

Here is the script execution with set -x enabled:

```
# set -o pipefail

HOSTS=./FILES/Solaris_Full_Inventory_Dec_2022.txt
+ HOSTS=./FILES/Solaris_Full_Inventory_Dec_2022.txt

cmd0="/usr/bin/id"
+ cmd0=/usr/bin/id
usernames=$(cat <<EOF
sac_haeaadmin
sac_botadmin
sac_appadmin
EOF
)
sac_haeaadmin
sac_botadmin
sac_appadmin
EOF
++ cat
+ usernames='sac_haeaadmin
sac_botadmin
sac_appadmin'

while read line; do
  [ "${line:0:1}" = "#" ] && continue
  echo $line;
for x in ${usernames}; do
       $(ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $line "${cmd0} $x");
     done
done<$HOSTS
+ read line
+ '[' C = '#' ']'
+ echo hostname1
hostname1
+ for x in ${usernames}
++ ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname1 '/usr/bin/id sac_haeaadmin'
+ 'uid=10201(sac_haeaadmin)' 'gid=1005(sugrp)'
./checkfor_username_solaris.sh: line 21: uid=10201(sac_haeaadmin): **command not found**
+ for x in ${usernames}
++ ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname2 '/usr/bin/id sac_botadmin'
+ 'uid=10202(sac_botadmin)' 'gid=20001(ibm)'
./checkfor_username_solaris.sh: line 21: uid=10202(sac_botadmin): command not found
+ for x in ${usernames}
++ ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname3 '/usr/bin/id sac_appadmin'
+ 'uid=10203(sac_appadmin)' 'gid=20002(appuser)'
./checkfor_username_solaris.sh: line 21: uid=10203(sac_appadmin): command not found
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I am fairly new to bash. TIA.
Jeff

script executes fine but with command not found, trying to understand why.

Comment: What is the name of the script?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: checkfor_username_solaris.sh

Comment: Looks like the $ was the culprit...though not sure why.
 
Line 21:
       $(ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $line "${cmd0} $x");
       ^-- SC2091 (warning): Remove surrounding $() to avoid executing output (or use eval if intentional).
                                               ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
       $(ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$line" "${cmd0} $x");

Comment: Add your script without `set -x`.

Comment: @user2766895 It's because that's what `$( )` does -- it captures the output from the command inside, and uses it as part of another command (in this case, the entire command, since there's nothing else there). If you don't want to capture the output and use it as part of another command, don't use `$( )`.

Comment: Compare `$(echo ls)`, `x=$(echo ls)` and `echo ls`. The first returns the string "ls" and runs printing a directory listing. The second assigns the string "ls" to variable "x". The third runs "echo ls". Now an `echo` command here is quite innocent. When you replace it with `ssh` you see that something more significant is happening. The `ssh` is  running a command on the remote machine, BUT, the output of the `ssh` command is also run on the local machine.

Comment: Do you need the command to run inside the subshell `$(...)`? You can put it in (...) without the `$` or you can drop the parenthesis altogether and run the ssh command as is.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to this line:

```
./checkfor_username_solaris.sh: line 21: uid=10201(sac_haeaadmin): command not found
```

That's not "calling itself", that's a formatted error message.

bash is telling you that there was an error on line 21 of "./checkfor_username_solaris.sh"

That's this line

```bash
       $(ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $line "${cmd0} $x");
```

The `$(...)` syntax is [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)
-- "substitution" being the key word here:

- the ssh command executes
- then the shell *replaces* the `$(...)` expansion with the *output of the command*
- then, since there's nothing else on the line, the shell **executes it as a command**.

Clearly, there's no command on your local machine named `uid=10201(sac_haeaadmin)`

You might want to capture the output and do something with it:

```bash
       output=$(ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $line "${cmd0} $x")
       do_something_with "$output"
```

Or, just let the ssh output be printed to stdout: remove the `$()` syntax

```bash
       ssh -qntT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $line "${cmd0} $x"
```

Comment: Trailing semicolons are not required in shell programs.